# How to compare attributes of the same table and SELECT based on that MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to take all the class tables that have more students that are male than female and list them

I've tried to do this a way that i'll show in the code

```
SELECT S.SID
FROM CLASS C, STUDENT S,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CLASS C, STUDENT S
WHERE S.GENDER = 'M') AS S(M),
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CLASS C, STUDENT S
WHERE S.GENDER = 'F') AS S1(F)
WHERE S.ClassNo = C.ClassNumber AND S(M) > S1(F)
```

I've tried it a few other ways including putting the select count statements in the 'where' place.  I can put the SELECT count statements separately outside of the big statement and it will show the correct values but for comparison, it is not working so I assume it has to do with how they're being compared.  I expect the output to show all the classes that have more males than females.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit all over the place. Assuming what you want is to get the class numbers where males>females:

```
select * from (
select c.ClassNumber, 
    sum(case when S.GENDER = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as m,
    sum(case when S.GENDER = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as f
from class c
join student s on s.ClassNo = C.ClassNumber
group by c.ClassNumber
) q
where m>f
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use aggregation:

```
SELECT S.CLASSNO
FROM STUDENT S
GROUP BY S.CLASSNO
HAVING SUM(GENDER = 'M') > SUM(GENDER = 'F');
```

Note that there is no need to use the `CLASS` table, because the class number is in the `STUDENT` table.